# Embedded Tomcat in a spring boot application is not resolving the variable in the swagger custom javascript file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring web application which is run using traditional method where I deploy the WAR file in the external tomcat webapps folder. Now I am trying to convert this web application into a spring boot web application.

The application has a swagger ui which has a login page when trying to login after successful authentication of the user the API's are fetched from **service.json** file. This is done via a GET Request URL `http://localhost:8080/video/api-docs/service.json`.

The webapps folder contains all the static files of swagger including a video.js file which contains a function as follows:

**video.js**

```
function initVideoService() {
    videoServiceSwagger = new SwaggerUi({
        url : "${URL}/api-docs/service.json",
        dom_id : "swagger-ui-container"
    });
```

The `${url}` has to resolved with `http://localhost:8080/videos` and then the url is built. This used to happen automatically when WAR file is deployed manually in external tomcat. But the internal tomcat is unable to resolve the place holder and it is returning `http://localhost:8080/videos/${url}/api-docs/service.json`. I am not sure whether it is tomcat issue or spring boot issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have searched for the ${URL} in my entire application and apart from the video.js file it is present in the pom.xml file inside the properties section.

Here is the pom.xml file

**Pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <URL>http://localhost:8080/videos</URL>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>
```

Also, I tried to replaced the ${URL} with it's value directly but still no luck. I am using **spring boot version 2.3.6.RELEASE**.

Comment: How the war application is built? Ant, Maven? Share the build script.